# Woocommerce- How to add tax on new line in email receipt

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to put the tax amount into next line in woocommerce order receipt. currently it shows:
Total:  $550.00(includes $50.00 Tax)

I wanted it like:
Total:  $550.00 
GST:    $50.00 (incl)

Can someone please help me on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it by hooking into the filter **woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html** . This filter is called inside the **wc_cart_totals_order_total_html** function, located in **/woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php**. Don't make change to this file but hooks to the filter instead.

The filter will allow you to modify the html content display after the *"Total"* label, so if you want to change it further, you might want to have a look at the Woocommerce template file **woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php**.

In case you are not familiar with overriding and working with Woocommerce templates, documentation can be found here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: @ Thai Duong Tran , I got that hook but it is only showing while reviewing order details. I would like to customize it in email receipt as well but I can't find a function/hook for that.